# ASP.NET Cross-Page Posting without PreviousPage

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-3.0, asp.net-3.5

I have a call to implement cross-page posting between two different web applications. Apparently, I cannot utilize the PreviousPage attribute in the markup file (ASPX). Could you shed some lights on this?

Thanks a lot!

Environment: ASP.NET 3.5 & IIS 6

Comment: PreviousPage wouldn't work across web applications. Just do a typical form POST and use the Request.Form object on the 2nd application to read in the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of Request.Form to capture data posted to that page.

```
Request.Form["someid"];
```

Comment: I tried to pass two hidden fields from the first page to the second page but unfortunately, the values became null at the second page. Could you show me some code samples? I used Button.PostBackUrl and two html hidden fields in the first page.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the code you already have so we can take a look at it?